# Solr: Number of posted files does not equal maxDoc

Tags: solr, indexing

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered somewhere - I wasn't able to find it.

I'm relatively new to Solr, and have been following the instructions given by the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/tutorial.html) for using the default SimplePostTool to index my data from the command line.  I'm currently using Solr 4.0 in my testing.

First, I delete everything in my index by query.  Then I point the SimplePostTool to several directories and index tens of thousands of files.  In my case, for right now, each XML file is a separate document. Some of the documents may have the same uniqueKey ID.  If it matters, the XML document sizes range from 4-60kB.

SimplePostTool returns when it's finished and says 26,541 files were indexed.  Then I look in the Admin collection1 page and see Num Docs = 20,985 and Max Doc = 22,921.

I've seen [other posts](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/numDocs-and-maxDoc-td484902.html) discussing the discrepancy between Num Docs and Max Doc (I feel I understand that overwrite behavior sufficiently).  My question is why the number of indexed docs reported by SimplePostTool does not match Max Doc given by the Solr Admin page?

Comment: "may have the same uniqueKey ID" that means that second upload overwrites the first; without any warning. In fact, in Solr, updating a document is same as adding a new document with same ID.

Comment: Right I understand that.  That's not my question, though.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you have different number of numDocs and maxDoc:

numDocs represents the number of searchable documents in the index (and will be larger than the number of XML files since some files contained more than one ). maxDoc may be larger as the maxDoc count includes logically deleted documents that have not yet been removed from the index. You can re-post the sample XML files over and over again as much as you want and numDocs will never increase, because the new documents will constantly be replacing the old.
From:[Solr official Tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/tutorial.html) . This apply for older versions.

You could remove logically deleted files by optimizing your index ->

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: "In my case...each XML file is a separate document." - in no case does one XML file contain more than one document.  I expect the reported number of documents indexed by the SimplePostTool to be >= numDocs, but never < numDocs.  So no problems there.  

Now as to my question - if maxDoc increments, even when overwriting documents that already exist in the index, then why is the number of documents indexed by the SimplePostTool != maxDoc?  I started with an empty index and just ran SimplePostTool on 26,541 docs.